# Need to export a database dump into csv format with headers and rows

Tags: mysql, database, csv

I've found several questions similar to this, but have not been able to export the data in a way that's usable in excel. I'm trying to export a table from a database and it does not display in columns with headers.

`mysqldump -u root -p dbname > filename.csv`

This outputs a csv file with the data in a single row and spread over many many columns with a bunch of extra stuff. I need a way to export the table with headers and columns so it can be reviewed and sorted in MS Excel.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

[SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) will generate a CSV file.